# How to import ES6 module in Vue file that is loaded by httpVueLoader?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ecmascript-6, http-vue-loader

I'm trying to use [urlJoin](https://www.skypack.dev/view/url-join) in a `Vue` single file component. I don't use a compiler and to load the `Vue` file I use `httpVueLoader`.

When I do this:

```
<script>

import urlJoin from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/url-join';

module.exports = { ...
```

The browser complains:

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Adding `type="module"` changes nothing, still the same error.

Is it possible to use it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it like that when using vue with npm

with npm:

```
npm install url-join
```

Usage:

```
var urljoin = require('url-join');
var fullUrl = urljoin('http://www.google.com', 'a', '/b/cd', '?foo=123');
```

The way you are using is not for npm check docs: https://www.skypack.dev/view/url-join